# Highcharts Get rid off bottom line

Tags: highcharts, line, axis

How can I get rid of the gray bottom line on axis X?

Any help please
[jsFiffle example](http://jsfiddle.net/EtvMR/)

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {text:''},
    yAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0,   
        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
        labels:{enabled: false},
        title: {enabled:false}
    },
    xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0,        
        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
        tickWidth: 0,
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb'],
        labels:{ enabled: false }
    },
    legend: {enabled: false},
    series: [{ data: [29.9, 71.5]  }]
});
```

});

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close, simply add `lineWidth: 0`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/EtvMR/2/

```
    xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
        tickWidth: 0,
        lineWidth: 0,
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb'],
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the CSS property `display: none` for the class selector `highcharts-axis` and it will disappear:

```
.highcharts-axis {
    display: none;
}
```

See: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/EtvMR/1/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a property for every axis called lineWidth which determines the width of the axis line.

setting it to a value will give the user defined width to the axis.

here it should be given as 0

```
lineWidth: 0
```

here I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EtvMR/3/) with changes

I hope this is what you are looking for.